How to organize footnotes to correspond to section divisions in the main text
I'm looking for a way to have sections in the footnotes that correspond to the section divisions in the text.
The page below is an example of what I want: a new chapter begins halfway down the page. There is a corresponding indication in the footnotes that a new chapter has begun. (Here it's shown with a line break and an inline header.)
(If it's relevant to the answer, I am also looking either to have the footnotes laid out in paragraph style, or at least in columns.)
I'm tagging reledmac because that seems to be the package with the best support for scholarly annotations, but I'm not committed to that package. (None of the relevant CTAN packages offer this feature, as far as I can see.)

Edit:
Here is reledmac code that gets very close to what I want. (The output is in an image below.) The question is whether I can start a new line—and perhaps add a header—in the footnotes when the chapter (here, the line number) changes.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainlanguage{latin}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[series={A},noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline
\Xragged[A]{R}
\Xsublinesep[A]{:}
\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

% begin new chapter
\setlinenum{3}
\startsub

\setline{15}
\startlock
This is chapter 3. (15) \edtext{Lorem ipsum}{\Afootnote{A critical note}} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \edtext{Nam consectetuer}{\Afootnote{A second note}} mollis dolor. Quisque malesuada nulla sed pede volutpat pulvinar. 
\endlock
\setline{16}
\startlock
(16) \edtext{Aliquam metus}{\Afootnote{A critical note}}. Morbi turpis arcu, egestas congue, condimentum quis, tristique cursus, leo. Mauris ac massa vestibulum nisl facilisis viverra. Mauris tincidunt aliquam ante. Curabitur tincidunt tellus nec purus. 
\endlock
\setline{17}
\startlock
(17) \edtext{Donec rutrum}{\Afootnote{A critical note}} venenatis dui. Nam sed nisl nec elit suscipit ullamcorper. Donec nonummy lacinia leo. Sed non ipsum. Curabitur nunc ante, ullamcorper vel, auctor a, aliquam at, tortor. 
\endlock
\endsub

% begin new chapter
\setlinenum{4}

\startsub
\setline{1}
\startlock
This is chapter 4. (1) \edtext{Quisque facilisis,}{\Afootnote{A critical note}} urna sit amet pulvinar mollis, purus arcu adipiscing velit, non condimentum diam purus eu massa. Morbi urna. Mauris et dolor. Praesent a lacus vitae turpis consequat semper. 
\endlock
\setline{2}
\startlock
(2) \edtext{Mauris sed}{\Afootnote{A critical note}} nulla quis nisi interdum tempor. Vivamus nisi elit, nonummy id, facilisis non, blandit ac, dolor. 
\endsub

\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}



You should look on the line number annotation feature of this package.

Thank you. I've added an MWE that gets close to what I want. I don't know if it's possible to insert spaces or headers when a line number (but not a subline) changes.

yers, there are example in the documentation to manage header...

I can't see anything in the documentation or examples about headers in the footnote section. (Perhaps you could suggest a word I could search for?) The example 2-one_series_per_pstart.pdf does show a way to create new series with a new chapter.

I made a confusion between "page header" and "section header". But I repeat : you should look on line number annotation system.

Ok, what you call divisionor header, I call them critical chapter.  And subsection critical verse, as for biblical chapter / biblical verse in your example (extract of Nestle-Aland).
What you need is

to disable line number printing, because the reference in your case is note line number
to have on level of critical footnote by chapter
to insert before each level of critical footnotes, the chapter number.

So the tricks is to have a dynamic \myfootnote macro, which can be plugged into \Afootnoteor \Bfootnote or \Cfootnote etc, depending of your chapter.
You may have many level of footnotes, that is not a problem, you have just to declare them in the preamble, when loading reledmac package.
And you have to store the current level.
So something like this should work.
\documentclass{article}
% In this example, we use the terme critical verse for what, in the question, is a biblical verse in the example
% And we use critical chapter for what, in the question, is header
% We use following option
%  - noend, nofamiliar because we dont need endnote and familiar note, so we improve perf
%  - noresetlinenumannotation because a critical verse must be on multiple physical line
% - series A et B, corresponding to each critical chapter : A -> 1, B -> 2 etc
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation,noend,nofamiliar,series={A,B}]{reledmac}
% Critical chapter

% \myfootnote is mapped to a footnote level corresponding to the critical chapter level
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommandx{\myfootnote}[2][1]{%
  \csuse{\int_to_Alph:n{\thecriticalchapter}footnote}[#1]{#2}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Insert chapter number before footnote ... do similar for more chapter / footnote level
\Xtxtbeforenotes[A]{\textbf{1}}
\Xtxtbeforenotes[B]{\textbf{2}}

% Typesetting criticalchapter and critical verse, annote line number
% We do not automatically increase because :
% - In context of critical edition, sometime we have lost chapter / verse
% - The way reledmac works makes complex to deal with counter between main text and footnote
\newcommand{\criticalchapter}[1]{%
  \resetlinenumannotation{}%
  \global\numdef{\thecriticalchapter}{#1}%
  \textbf{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\criticalverse}[1]{%
  \textsuperscript{#1}%
  \linenumannotation{#1}%
}

% We arrange note in paragraph, one by critical chapter
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xparafootsep{\space$||$\space}
\Xafternote{0pt}


\Xafternumber{0.25em}% Styling annotation

% Some things not to be showed
\firstlinenum{999999999}% No marginal number
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}% Not real line number in footnote
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation
\Xtwolines{\relax}
\Xmorethantwolines{\relax}
\Xinplaceofnumber{0pt}
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\criticalchapter{1}\criticalverse{1} \edtext{First paragraph, first verse}{\myfootnote{So : 1.1}}.
\criticalverse{2} \edtext{First paragraph, second}{\myfootnote{So: 1.2}} a long long long \edtext{second critical verse}{\myfootnote{So: 1.2 again}}.
\criticalchapter{2}\criticalverse{1}
\edtext{Second paragraph, first verse}{\myfootnote{So : 2.1}}.
\criticalverse{2}\edtext{Second paragraph, second verse}{\myfootnote{So 2.2}}.
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}

